# Apache: Allow from IP or username based

Tags: apache-2.2

I want to configure Apache to allow connections from A specific IP or otherwise based on usernames. Is this possible? For now I am having this configuration which is username based.

```
<Directory />

    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
<Location />
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain DOMAINNAME
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    Require group GROUP_NAME
</Location>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the "satisfy" condition :

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 88.88.88.89
Allow from 88.89.90.91
Deny from all

Satisfy any
```

that means if the user does not have the ip 'Allow from', he will be asked to enter a password